# List files and download

Tags: php, form, file-system

The following code list all files in a folder and allows the user to download one of them. It is working but I think it could be done better.

Is there a way to reduce the number of forms to only one and to improve the way I retrieve the name of the file to download?

My second concern is about the security of my `getFile` function.

```
function listDir($directoryName)
{
    $directory = opendir($directoryName);
    $files = array();
    while ($elem = readdir($directory))
    {
        if ($elem != '.' && $elem != '..' && $elem != '.htaccess')
        {
            $files[] = $elem;
        }
    }
    closedir();
    if (!empty($directory))
    {
        sort($files);
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $filePath = $directoryName.'/'.$file;
            echo "<form method='post' action=".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).">";
            echo "<li>($fileDate)";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='$file' value='$filePath'>";
            echo " <button type='submit' name='getFile'>Télécharger</button> ";
            echo "$file</li>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

function getFile($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['getFile']))
{
    $keys = array_keys($_POST);
    $file = $_POST[$keys[0]];
    getFile($file);
}

listDir('data');
```

Comment: Your `getFile` function is *incredibly* insecure. The number one rule is to never trust the user. I could POST `getFile=/var/etc/passwd` or `getFile=../my/secret/file` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's post a dry review first, before jumping in to the conceptual stuff:

- You are allowing your end-users download any file on the server. All I need to do is to change the path to `/etc/passwd` on any form and submit, and I get your server's password file! And if I don't have permissions to that, no biggy, I can still download all of your owned files on the server.
- Invalid HTML markup - `<form>` isn't allowed directly inside of `<ul>`. Only `<li>` is.
- Separate logic and presentation - You shouldn't mix the part where the user sees your form, and the part where he downloads the file.

### A better approach?

A better approach would be a PHP file which is capable of serving files. That PHP file needs to make sure that the file being requested is found in a very specific list of allowed directories (i.e. I allow from `images/` and from `static/` but not from anywhere else.

Then, when you download a file, all you need to do is to link (With an `<a>`) to

```
http://example.com/path/to/file_server.php?filename=somefile.jpg
```

And have the PHP `file_server` handle the serving of the requested file.

#### Getting Fancy

You can even use `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` to rewrite URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/static/somefile.jpg
```

to

```
http://example.com/path/to/file_server.php?filename=somefile.jpg
```

Making the fact that PHP is the one sending the file completely transparent to the user!

Comment: Taking into account your advice, I replaced my `getFile` with [this script](http://www.media-division.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/) (improved with `$finfo = new finfo; $ctype = $finfo->file($file, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);` for the MIME)